# Strange Plot result

Tags: plotting

When I plot this function

```
collisionProb[distA_, velA_, radA_, velP_, radP_] := 
 With[{\[Sigma] = (velA * distA)/(2 * velP), l = radA + radP}, 
  Probability[-l <= x <= l, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]]]]
```

with the command

```
Plot[collisionProb[10, x, 0.2, 10, 0.1], {x, 0, 11}]
```

I get this...

[image]

which seems strange to me. For example,

```
collisionProb[10, 1, 0.2, 10, 0.1]
```

evaluates to 0.451494.

What's wrong with that plot command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a collision of variables in that `x` is used two ways (as the variable in the probability function and as the iterator in the `Plot`). Variables in Mathematica are global. Plot using:

```
Plot[collisionProb[10, z, 0.2, 10, 0.1], {z, 0, 11}]
```

Comment: The reason for this variable collision is the fact (stated under *Details and Options* in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html?q=Plot)), that `Plot` treats `x` as a local variable, effectively using `Block`. Therefore the global `x` inside `Probability` becomes the same local `x` as the second argument of `collisionProb`.